# Alternatives to EntityManager's merge() method

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, entitymanager

I was wondering if there is a way to perform an update other than using the merge() method, there are lots of cases where I just need to update a single field on the database, and to do it I have to bring the entire object from the db with all its relationships, set new new value, and then call the merge method passing the modified object. It works fine, but it's causing some performance issues, since I have to unnecessarily bring some data from the database before the update. The way I see, it would be better to just execute the update without bringing any data to the memory.

Has anyone already thought about it and came up with an alternative and more effective way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a "Native query" with an UPDATE, or use a JPQL UPDATE (as per uaiHebert comment). It can affect multiple records. It comes with the proviso that no event handlers are called, and any instances already in memory will not be updated automatically, just the datastore. See http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/jpa/jpql.html#update-syntax

Comment: You could do a Update with JPQL also. [=